# UIAlertView with UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput slow to appear (first time)

Tags: ios, uialertview, uikeyboardtype

I'm showing an Alert view when a user selects a cell in a table. (on an iPad 4 running ios 7.0.4)

If the Alert is plain (no textview), it shows immediately.

If it has a TextView, it takes a couple of seconds (but only the first time).

my code;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create?" message:@"Enter name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;        

    [alert show]; // doesnt make a difference if I use performSelectorOnMain here.
}
```

I've tried with and without the performSelector - it's always slow the first time. Any Ideas?

I've tested some more;

- It's quick in the simulator.
- It's quick if i start it directly on the ipad.
- **It's slow if i start it through xcode.**

Comment: may be problem with threading of GCD .simply you put [alert show];....

Comment: Tableview delegate methods are called on main thread, so you don't need to `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` for alert view `show`. Does this happen on simulator or device?

Comment: Can you comment out lines 3,4 (where you access textfield and set `keyboardType`) and check if its still slow?

Comment: I've tried using [alert show] - was my original version. I thought the tableview would be on main, but I was trying everything I could before posting.

Comment: This is running on a device.
It's not slow with the textField and keyboardType commented out.

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this? I'm having exactly the same issue

Comment: It's only slow when running in the debugger, so I didn't look into it any further. (It works fine otherwise).